# Spring boot jar deploy file upload system

Tags: java, spring-boot

hello sir i build the springboot app which serves as backend for electron app which we made from react so i was saving file inside project folder resource>static and saving the details of photo in database as localhost:9000/hello.png ...in development phase i was able to get the image by that name which i have stored in database but when i build a jar file and tried to run it i was able to create file but cannot get the file
and my requirment is i have to run that server locally also and in future in cloud also

```
/**class that have server url
public class KanchanjungaApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static final String SERVERURL = "http://localhost:9000/";
**/

and this is my code that saves file  
package Kanchanjunga.Utility;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.rmi.server.UID;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import Kanchanjunga.KanchanjungaApplication;

@Component
public class FilesHelper {
    public String saveFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        // uid for unique name of image
        UID uid = new UID();
        String uidString = uid.toString().replace(':', '_');
        String originalFilename = file.getOriginalFilename();
        String extension = "";
        if (originalFilename != null) {
            int dotIndex = originalFilename.lastIndexOf('.');
            if (dotIndex >= 0) {
                extension = originalFilename.substring(dotIndex);
                originalFilename = originalFilename.substring(0, dotIndex);
            }
        }
        String filename = originalFilename + "_" + uidString + extension;
        String uploadDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/static";
                Path paths = Paths.get(uploadDir);
        if (!Files.exists(paths)) {
            Files.createDirectories(paths);
        }
        Path imagePath = paths.resolve(filename);
        try (InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream()) {
            Files.copy(inputStream, imagePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Fail to save file " + filename, e);
        }
        return KanchanjungaApplication.SERVERURL + filename;
    }

    public Boolean deleteExistingFile(String fileName) {
        String uploadDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/static";
        String filePathString = fileName.replace(KanchanjungaApplication.SERVERURL, "");
        Path filePath = Paths.get(uploadDirectory, filePathString);
        try {
            Files.deleteIfExists(filePath);
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

i researched and tried to find solution but failed i really need help and your expertise`

Comment: The file is hardly stored in a database, it is stored on the local disk. `src/main/resources` may be easily available when you are running the application locally but after the application is built and deployed, that directory is not automatically available to serve content through a web server. If you are going for this solution you need to store the file in a directory that is available to the web server.

Comment: Quite right. Don't use your source tree. You want `Path filename = Path.of(originalFilename, "_", uidString, extension);Path dest = Path.of(System.getProperty("user.home"), filename);` You might not want to put the file in your home directory, in which case choose another. But be aware that `user.dir` is redundant as the default target would be the current directory anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically create directory in project's root directory to save uploaded files this way

```
public static final String UPLOAD_DIR = "uploads/images/";

@Component
public class FilesHelper {
    public String saveFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        File fileSaveDir = new File(UPLOAD_DIR);
        if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
            fileSaveDir.mkdirs();
        }
    }
}
```

After deploying the directory will be created in `tomcat/bin`

For local test you can save uploaded file url in database as

```
http://localhost:9000/uploads/images/hello.png
```

After deploying url will be

```
http://yourdomain.com:9000/YourJarFileName/uploads/images/hello.png
```

Therefore you should change upload base url before building jar to be deployed

eg. change

```
http://localhost:9000/
```

to

```
http://yourdomain.com:9000/YourJarFileName/
```