# How can we manage files in spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How can we manage and store files in database using spring boot are we store file itself in database or store path of the file or only name of the file and then how we can handle API request for file along with its metadata ?

Comment: *store files in database* please, dont.

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76962580/spring-boot-jar-deploy-file-upload-system/76977184#76977184)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.