# Add an image from <input type="file"> through <form method="post"> to the /static/images and the name of the image to MySQL

Tags: java, spring-boot, forms, spring-mvc

My DB `Day` model has fields: timestamp such as id, description, content, steps, mainImage. The constructor is empty with default values ​​if there is no such timestamp in the database. "non-empty" if timestamp is in BD, getters/setters. There is a view `full_day.html` with info and an Edit Day button. When clicked Edit, a modal window opens with a form for changing the day using the "Save" button.

In short, I want my user to add an image to a form (and some other things) and the image file goes to the /static/images/ and the file name goes to the MySQL Table. What are the ideas to do?

(It is the details of the info I described above)

**CalendarController.java**:

```java
// Other methods
@GetMapping("/{year}/{month}/{dayNumber}")
public String day(Model model,
                  @PathVariable int year,
                  @PathVariable String month,
                  @PathVariable int dayNumber) {

    long timestamp = convertToDateTimestamp(year, month, dayNumber);

    Optional<Day> gotDay = dayRepository.findById(timestamp);
    ArrayList<Day> currentDay = new ArrayList<>();

    gotDay.ifPresent(currentDay::add);

    model.addAttribute("gotDay", gotDay);
    model.addAttribute("currentDay", currentDay);
    model.addAttribute("year", year);
    model.addAttribute("month", month);
    model.addAttribute("dayNumber", dayNumber);
    return "full_day";
}

@PostMapping("/{year}/{month}/{dayNumber}")
public String saveDay(Model model,
                      @ModelAttribute("gotDay") Day currentDay,
                      @PathVariable int year,
                      @PathVariable String month,
                      @PathVariable int dayNumber
) {

    currentDay.setTimestamp(convertToDateTimestamp(year, month, dayNumber));
    dayRepository.save(currentDay);

    return "redirect:/calendar/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + dayNumber;
}
```

**Day.java:**

```java
@Entity
@Table(schema = "memoryfulday", name = "memoryful")
public class Day {
    @Id
    private Long timestamp;
    private String description, content;
    private int steps;
    private String mainImage;
//    private MultipartFile mainImage;

    public Day(Long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.mainImage = "NoPhoto.png";
        this.description = "No brief description";
        this.steps = 0;
        this.content = "No content";
    }

    public Day(Long timestamp, String mainImage, String description, String content, int steps) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.mainImage = mainImage;
        this.description = description;
        this.content = content;
        this.steps = steps;
    }

    // toString()
    // getters/setters
}
```

**full_day.html:**

```html
<!-- some code -->
<div id="edit-modal" class="edit-modal">
    <div class="edit-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h2>Edit Day Window</h2>

        <form method="post" th:object="${gotDay}">
            <label for="steps">Daily steps</label>
            <input value="${day.steps}" th:field="*{steps}" id="steps" type="number" tabindex="1" placeholder="10000">

            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <input value="${day.description}" th:field="*{description}" id="description" type="text" tabindex="2" placeholder="Enter day's description">

            <label for="content">Content</label>
            <textarea th:text="${day.content}" th:field="*{content}" id="content" tabindex="3" placeholder="Enter day's content"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" tabindex="4" class="left-right" id="editSubmit" value="Save">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

// some js to interract with modal window
```

I watched videos, searched info in websites, but I didn't find what I wanted. I tried some code that ChatGPT wrote for me, but it couldn't help me.

Comment: To post data & files, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76655712/how-to-receive-an-entity-with-image-from-requestparam/76677954#76677954). To generate directory to upload files to you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76962580/spring-boot-jar-deploy-file-upload-system/76977184#76977184)